# How do I use a regular expression to match a string with one pattern but not another pattern?

Tags: regex, string

I need to determine whether a string matches one substring, but not another.  For example, given the substrings "john" and "mary", where "john" must be present and "mary" must not:

"My name is john" -> matches

"My name is mary" -> no match

"Their names are john and mary" -> no match

Note that the two strings are not interchangeable, "john" is always the one to be matched, and "mary" must never match, so it is not a simple XOR operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your regex:

```
^(?!mary)(.(?!mary))*john(?!mary)(.(?!mary))*$
```

Ok, I'll explain it since your question was "how". :)
`^` marks the beginning.
`(?!mary)` is a negative lookahead. It matches if there is no "mary" at the current position. After that any character not followed by "mary" is eaten until "john" is reached. Then the whole mary check is done again until the end, which is marked by the dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you split up this problem into two parts?

- check whether `john` occurs in the string. If it is present, go on. Otherwise return `false`
- now check whether `mary` occurs in the string. If it is present, return `false`, otherwise `true`

Now combine both tests into one method.

Comment: I like this approach.  Works nice with a short-circuit AND.  In JavaScript: `return s.indexOf(john)>=0 && s.indexOf(mary)<0;`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this.  This is for an online tool that enforces certain rules based on a single regex, so I can't write code to do it, and I can't use multiple regexs